# How to use Non Negative Matric Factorization (NMF)'s transform method to project topics on new text data

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, topic-model

I have created a NMF topic model in python the code snippet for which is as follows:

```
def select_vectorizer(req_ngram_range=[1,2]):
    ngram_lengths = req_ngram_range
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(ngram_lengths), stop_words='english', min_df=2)
    #print("User specified custom stopwords: {} ...".format(str(custom_stopwords)[1:-1]))
    return vectorizer

vectorizer = select_vectorizer([2,5])
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_review_list)


clf = decomposition.NMF(n_components=20, random_state=3, alpha = .1).fit(X)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(clf, vocab, num_top_words)
```

which created 20 topics like the following:

```
Topic #0:
[u'blocks available', u'delivery blocks available', u'notifications blocks', u'notifications blocks available', u'new blocks', u'know blocks available', u'new blocks available', u'know blocks', u'open blocks available', u'available work', u'zero blocks', u'like blocks', u'notification blocks', u'day blocks', u'slow blocks', u'10 blocks', u'option set', u'logged 10', u'notification blocks available', u'day blocks available']
Topic #1:
['something', 'something'] and so on..
```

Now I want to supply new text data to this fitted NMF model such that the model tells us which topic this new text belongs to. I have searched a lot, somebody suggested using "transform", but I do not know how to use it. For eg: if I have a new text, like:

```
new_feedback = "This is a new tester feedback"
```

Then how do I find which topic out of the 20 topics created earlier, does this `new_feedback` fall into? Please help!!

UPDATE: On trying to do what's mentioned in the below comment, I receive the following error:

```
clf.transform(vectorizer.transform(new_feedback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1380, in transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).transform(raw_documents)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 884, in transform
    "Iterable over raw text documents expected, "
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use topics created by topic model to predict on new text data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19070/how-to-use-topics-created-by-topic-model-to-predict-on-new-text-data)

Comment: We already discussed this! Try something like `clf.transform(vectorizer.transform(new_feedback))`. The idea is to obtain the TF-IDF representation of our text, then to project it onto your word/topic space. Do you understand the theory behind this? If not, you should study linear algebra.

Comment: @Emre I have already tried what you're saying and it gives me an error which I've added in the question.

Comment: So enclose the text in a list (iterable). Please pay attention to the error messages.

Comment: @Emre Okay thanks. But, how do I interpret the output obtained? It is coming as follows: [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.86051087e-03   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.51227091e-04   
    0.00000000e+00   7.22981207e-30   0.00000000e+00      3.96366949e-04   5.64132704e-03   1.38391978e-01
    5.82677612e-03   2.65624786e-03
    1.51336032e-02 9.42873715e-03
    0.00000000e+00   2.22575193e-02   5.91616082e-03   4.52357765e-03]]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should get your topics and corresponding words. You first get the NMF transformation of your new input and sort its components. The biggest components tell you which features to look at in nmf.components_, which links topics to words (your tfidf features). Finally, you print the k most important words of the topics. Topics and words scores are just calculated by dividing their value by the sum of all values.

```
    import numpy as np
    # Transform new_feedback to NMF space
    nmf_new_feedback = clf.transform(vectorizer.fit(new_feedback))
    # top 10 topics of the new feedback
    compo = np.argsort(nmf_new_feedback)[-10:][::-1]
    # Connection between indices and words of tfidf
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    for topic_idx in compo:
        # Current nmf topic
        topic = nmf.components_[topic_idx]
        print("Topic number: ", topic_idx)
        print("Topic score: ", nmf_new_feedback[topic_idx]/sum(nmf_new_feedback))
        # Top 15 words of current topic
        for k in topic.argsort()[-15:][::-1]]
            print("Word: ",feature_names[k], "  Score: ", topic[k]/ sum(topic))
```

Comment: There is an error on the 2nd last line. Wrong brackets?

Comment: Also when I do clf.transform(vectorizer.fit(new_feedback)) I get an error: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py", line 1086, in transform
    beta=self.beta, eta=self.eta)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py", line 744, in non_negative_factorization
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 402, in check_array
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: But no error when I use: clf.transform(vectorizer.transform(new_feedback)) What's happening?

Comment: Its definitely "vectorizer.transform". Sorry for the mistakes, I didn't try this code. But the main idea is here :-)